# Podman w/Docker Compose - run as user?

Tags: non-root-user, podman, docker-compose

I'm trying out `docker-compose` with Podman which according to [this](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-docker-compose) is now supported. I run the instructions and can indeed hit the socket when running as root but when I try as user I get:

> permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket
> at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
> "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dproject%22%3Atrue%7D%7D":
> dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Is it possible to use `podman` with `docker-compose` with user privileges? Or do you have to be root?

### Edit

Added the docker group and then added my user to it then rebooted to be absolutely certain the changes would take efect:

```
[grant@rockylinux docker-compose-files]$ ./compose.sh setup --project
Pass: Docker compose version is 2.15.1.
Running docker-compose --project-directory /home/grant/project -f /home/grant/project/docker-compose-files/docker-compose.yml --profile project up  -d
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dproject%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
[grant@rockylinux docker-compose-files]$ cat /etc/group
...SNIP...
grant:x:1000:
docker:x:1001:grant
```

### Edit 2

Tested the curl command in the aforementioned blog post. It works as root but not as user

```
[grant@rockylinux docker-compose-files]$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/_ping
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
[grant@rockylinux docker-compose-files]$ sudo curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/_ping
OK
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set podman up to run as a user.

1. If you have already set podman up to run with `systemctl enable podman` you will need to reverse that with `systemctl disable --now podman podman.socket`. If you have previously installed `podman-docker` you will notice that the soft link from `/var/run/docker.sock` to `/run/podman/podman.sock` will now be broken because `podman` is now no longer running under root
2. Next you will need to setup podman to use a user service with `systemctl enable --now --user podman podman.socket`. This will create a socket at `/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock`. Notice that this socket is owned by user. See [here](https://nts.strzibny.name/systemd-user-services/) for more details on user services. TLDR: Instead of running the service when the system starts, it runs it at user login.
3. Finally, we need to set the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to [point at our new socket](https://podman-desktop.io/docs/migrating-from-docker/using-the-docker_host-environment-variable). You can do this with `export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock`. **WARNING**: Your path could be different. You can check the socket podman is using with `podman info --format '{{.Host.RemoteSocket.Path}}'`.

If you need to debug, you can get debug output from the podman service with `podman --log-level=debug system service -t0`. You can check connectivity to the socket itself with `` curl --unix-socket /run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock -X GET http://d/version`[d]` ``

Comment: Grant, is it possible to run the podman service as a system service, but have the socket owned by the docker group instead of by root by default? Is this a systemctl option, maybe?

Comment: ‍♂️ these are more characters so that stackoverflow will let me post

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use Podman with Docker Compose with user privileges. The error message you are seeing is indicating that the user you are running the command as does not have permission to access the Docker daemon socket. To fix this, you can add your user to the "docker" group, which will give it the necessary permissions to access the socket.

You can do this by running the following command:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker yourusername
```

You will need to log out and log back in for the changes to take effect. After that, you should be able to run Docker Compose commands using Podman without needing to be root.

Comment: Hmmm I could have sworn I did that but you know I may have forgotten - will go back and give it a go today. That would be embarrassing 

Comment: Negative - doesn't look like that was it. I have updated the OP with exactly what I did. Maybe I'm still missing something?

Comment: You can try to run the command as the root user and check the versions of podman and docker-compose, and compare it with the version of podman that you are using.

You can also try running the command with the --verbose flag to see more detailed information about what is causing the error.

Another thing you could check is if there are any other processes running that are using the same socket file, which could be causing a conflict. You can use the command lsof -i :/var/run/docker.sock to check for other processes that are using the socket file.

Comment: I just hit this issue - the problem is tyhat the Unix socket is not owned by the docker group, it's root:root. You need to do more to change the group of the socket, or (as another answer suggested) run the podman-docker service as a user service, which kind of sucks.