# podman running as user dies after hard reboot - Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (22: Invalid argument)

Tags: container, namespace, podman, setgid

I'm struggling to determine what is going on here. Podman running in user space was running fine, but the server took a hard reboot and now it is... for lack of a more accurate technical assessment, borked.

```
[grant@patches2 patches]$     podman build       --tag local/patches-python:latest       --squash-all       -f ${SCRIPT_DIR}/python_container/Dockerfile.python       --build-arg "PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR=podman-build/python_container"       ${TOP_DIR}
[1/2] STEP 1/7: FROM python:3.12.0a7-slim-bullseye AS builder
[1/2] STEP 2/7: ARG PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR
[1/2] STEP 3/7: WORKDIR /app
[1/2] STEP 4/7: RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libffi-dev
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (22: Invalid argument)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (22: Invalid argument)
Reading package lists...
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (22: Invalid argument)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (22: Invalid argument)
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (22: Invalid argument)
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (112)
Error: building at STEP "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libffi-dev": while running runtime: exit status 100
[grant@patches2 patches]$ cat /etc/subuid
root:200000:1001
grant:200000:1001
[grant@patches2 patches]$ cat /etc/subgid
root:200000:1001
grant:200000:1001
[grant@patches2 patches]$ podman system migrate
[grant@patches2 patches]$     podman build       --tag local/patches-python:latest       --squash-all       -f ${SCRIPT_DIR}/python_container/Dockerfile.python       --build-arg "PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR=podman-build/python_container"       ${TOP_DIR}
[1/2] STEP 1/7: FROM python:3.12.0a7-slim-bullseye AS builder
[1/2] STEP 2/7: ARG PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR
[1/2] STEP 3/7: WORKDIR /app
[1/2] STEP 4/7: RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libffi-dev
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (22: Invalid argument)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (22: Invalid argument)
Reading package lists...
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (22: Invalid argument)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (22: Invalid argument)
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (22: Invalid argument)
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (112)
Error: building at STEP "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libffi-dev": while running runtime: exit status 100
[grant@patches2 patches]$ cat /etc/group | grep 65534
nobody:x:65534:
```

I'm a bit at a loss as to where to go with this one as it's not at all clear to me what the problem is.

Here is the dockerfile in question:

```
FROM python:3.12.0b4-slim-bookworm AS builder

ARG PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR

WORKDIR /app

# Install build essentials for compiling C code
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libffi-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Copy files to the working directory
COPY ${PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR}/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Production stage
FROM python:3.12.0b4-slim-bookworm

ARG PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR

WORKDIR /app

# Copy files from the build stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/
COPY ${PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR}/generate_certificates.py .
COPY ${PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR}/generate_certificates_entrypoint.sh .
COPY ${PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR}/configure_nginx.py .
COPY ${PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR}/configure_nginx_entrypoint.sh .
COPY ${PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR}/import_keys.py .
COPY ${PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR}/import_keys_entrypoint.sh .
COPY ${PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR}/helper_functions.py .

RUN chmod +x ./generate_certificates_entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./configure_nginx_entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./import_keys_entrypoint.sh
```

This seems like it might be a bug internal to podman? I'm not quite sure what to look at here.

### Updated subuid/subgid

```
[1/2] STEP 1/7: FROM python:3.12.0a7-slim-bullseye AS builder
[1/2] STEP 2/7: ARG PYTHON_CONTAINER_DIR
[1/2] STEP 3/7: WORKDIR /app
[1/2] STEP 4/7: RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libffi-dev
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (22: Invalid argument)
E: seteuid 100 failed - seteuid (22: Invalid argument)
E: setgroups 0 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb': Permission denied
Reading package lists...
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (22: Invalid argument)
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (22: Invalid argument)
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (22: Invalid argument)
E: seteuid 100 failed - seteuid (22: Invalid argument)
E: setgroups 0 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (112)
Error: building at STEP "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libffi-dev": while running runtime: exit status 100
[grant@patches2 patches]$ cat /etc/subuid
root:200000:1001
grant:200000:65536
[grant@patches2 patches]$ cat /etc/subgid
root:200000:1001
grant:200000:65536
[grant@patches2 patches]$
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> grant:200000:1001
> ```

Your mapping last value is a count (of UIDs), not an UID or GID. So here 1001 doesn't mean UID 1001, but a pool of 1001 mappable values between 200000 and 201000.

podman will use setuidmap/setgidmap to map the user's range. It doesn't do anything fancy: the current user becomes 0 (root) and the simple continuous range between 200000 and 201000 (included) will be mapped to 1-1001

As 65534 > 1001 it's not mapped and this creates an error (EINVAL) when used inside the container.

Note that the value 1001 is not what is created by default by the system when creating an user. The normal range is 65536, compatible with legacy 2^16 possible values and there can never be such problem.

The easiest fix is to edit (as root) `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` to have the usual range of 65536 values by replacing 1001 with 65536. If this would overlap with an other user, you should choose a new unused range instead. (Note that currently your two users *root* and *grant* have the same mappings: they do overlap, which isn't great from an accountability point of view).

There are other options with `podman run` (`--uid-map` + `--gid-map` or else `--userns`) to use a limited range of UIDs/GIDs but they all appear to involve the root user before or during.

Comment: I’m familiar with that but I thought nobody’s ID was handled as an exception. I’ll check that out but I think I tried something similar yesterday. I may be confusing things though

Comment: @GrantCurell No: the overflow ID is mapped as nobody. Not the other way around.

Comment: gave it a shot - it's a new day so I'm back to work on it, but the results appear to be the same. If it helps, this is how I have podman setup: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731645/podman-w-docker-compose-run-as-user/734790#734790. I'm going to try to dig deeper and figure out more specifically what is causing the error message. I have been using the originally mentioned uid/gid mapping without issue with exactly this build up until the non-graceful reset. I just can't think of what would cause this behavior to emerge after a reboot.

Comment: I did what this guy suggested `https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/11217#discussioncomment-1814513`, though I also had to reboot to get the subuid/subgid changes to take effect. That worked but what I did in my update didn't - I'm not sure why though