# podman1: port 1(veth0) entered disabled blocking state / podman does not gracefully shutdown

Tags: systemd, reboot, podman

I have podman setup as I described in [this answer on Unix&Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/734790/240147). I am running this on Rocky Linux 9.

I have further set up my user session to linger with `loginctl enable-linger $(whoami)` so that I can have the podman process run with systemd on startup. My systemd file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Patches Service
Wants=network.target
After=network.target
Requires=user@${USER}.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutStartSec=10min
ExecStart=/bin/bash ${SCRIPT_DIR}/patches.sh start --continuous

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

where the patches.sh script runs a series of containers all sharing a common container network backend. Ex:

```
    podman run \
      --name patches-nginx \
      --env-file ${TOP_DIR}/.patches-nginx \
      --volume ${SCRIPT_DIR}/nginx_config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:Z \
      --volume ${TOP_DIR}/${CERT_DIRECTORY}:/patches/${CERT_DIRECTORY}:z \
      --publish 443:443 \
      --publish 80:80 \
      --detach \
      --network host-bridge-net \
      --restart=always \
      docker.io/library/nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}
```

I notice that after this setup the following happens when restarting the server:

[image]

I'm in the process of debugging but it's not clear to me what is causing this hang up. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have restart policies assigned to the containers themselves that conflict with systemd. When I used `podman generate systemd` I saw:

```
WARN[0000] Container 59590e79e4fc95158b74360fa6491a907c6a7cafa1b24d9ff34117a8a15cfc03 has restart policy "unless-stopped" which can lead to issues on shutdown: consider recreating the container without a restart policy and use systemd's restart mechanism instead
```

and

```
WARN[0000] Container 574fd77e6dc57eeac56358003e73ecf122058d3c212201c5b24b200c836df798 has restart policy "always" which can lead to issues on shutdown: consider recreating the container without a restart policy and use systemd's restart mechanism instead
```

when using systemd you should use systemd's policies ex: `Restart=on-failure` to restart the container instead of the container itself. If you don't the container will thrash on shutdown.

Comment: If you actually generate a proper systemd unit per container, the `unless-stopped` policy won't thrash on shutdown (but it still offers no advantage over systemd's native Restart policy). `always` on the other hand will. `podman generate systemd` is clearly the way to go, especially if you're starting the containers through a unit anyway.