# podman - containers stuck in stopping state after reboot

Tags: container, podman

I have now bumped into this problem several times - some podman containers get stuck in the stopping state, but I'm not sure how to tackle the problem.

```
[grant@patches patches]$ podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                               COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                     NAMES
434645aa71eb  docker.io/library/postgres:15.3     postgres              40 minutes ago  Stopping                                                 patches-psql
```

no amount of force killing seems to stop the process. Ex:

```
[grant@patches patches]$ podman kill patches-psql
2023-08-11T19:17:28.307348Z: open pidfd: No such process
Error: container state improper: stopped
[grant@patches patches]$ podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                               COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                     NAMES
434645aa71eb  docker.io/library/postgres:15.3     postgres              52 minutes ago  Stopping                                                 patches-psql
```

I can remove the container with `rm -f` but I haven't found a way to force it to stop and then restart it.

Comment: Can you check a `ps faux` to determine whether this is a "process won't die" issue or a "podman doesn't detect stopped container" issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen other people post about this elsewhere on the internet so I don't want to close this question, but I was able to resolve this after I implemented the answer I wrote [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753846/240147).

Basically what had happened is that I had a systemd service that was controlling the containers but the containers had restart polices like restart always. These conflicted so that when systemd would try to terminate the container the container would try to restart itself.

I'm not exactly sure why certain containers got stuck in the stopping state, but the PIDs existed nowhere so they were in fact dead.